# Quadratic residues of Fermat primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a Fermat prime $p=2^{2^k}+1$, I can show that every quadratic nonresidue mod $p$ is also a primitive root for $p$, by showing that there are $(p-1)/2$ primitive roots.

However, I am wondering how to show the converse implication: given a prime $p$, to show that if every quadratic nonresidue is a primitive root, then $p$ is necessarily a Fermat prime. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Recall there are $\phi(p-1)$ generators of the multiplicative group mod $p$, and use $\phi(n)=n\prod_{\text{prime }\ell\mid n}(1-\frac1\ell)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Hi, I have the following: by assumption $p$ has $(p-1)/2$ primitive roots, so $\phi(p-1)=(p-1)/2$. From your hint, I have $\phi(p-1)=(p-1)\prod_{\ell\mid(p-1)}(1-1/\ell)$, which gives $1/2=\prod_{\ell\mid(p-1)}(1-1/\ell)$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, though!

Answer (score 1):

Consider an odd prime $p$; this has a primitive root $g$. Now $g^i$ is also a primitive root iff $\gcd(i,p{-}1)=1$ so there are [$\phi(p{-}1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) primitive roots. Since $p{-}1$ is even, $\phi(p{-}1)\leq(p{-}1)/2$ and the only case when $\phi(p{-}1)=(p{-}1)/2$ will be when $p{-}1$ has no odd factors, so $p{-}1$ is a power of $2$ and $p{-}1= 2^m$.

Then [since $2^m+1$ is prime, $m$ must also be a power of $2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Other_theorems_about_Fermat_numbers) as required.